# Ubuntu failed to start servers while turning on the machine

Tags: 18.04

When I tried to turned on my ubuntu machine. It is not able to start the services and it halted on this screen itself(Screenshort attached below). Here I have attached my screen below.

Earlier, I got a notification regards - Running out of space and the Ubuntu notified me to Empting the Trash.

Does the issue is occuring because of Empted the Trash
[ubuntufailedtostartservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsstl.jpg)

Comment: By *start the servers*?  do you mean 'start services'?   As you mention running out of space, did you switch to a text terminal & check if there is space? and then erase or allocate more space if required? or `fsck` your partitions or try anything?

Comment: @guiverc No I have not check for space and also I havn't tried anything.